# Messages not posting in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Posts are not appearing in chat right now. When a user posts something, it often doesn't show up, as confirmed by various users. On my end, posts are staying green, indicating that they are not posting. Furthermore, new messages won't show up unless chat is refreshed. What is going on?

Comment: [meta-tag:status-reproduced]. I've asked a dev to look into it.

Comment: Is this still happening? We had some issues with chat following a SQL server upgrade, but I believe those have been resolved now.

Comment: @Adam It hasn't been happening for me for hours now, nor have I seen anyone else reporting it. I'll go ahead and mark this [tag:status-completed] unless you wanna do the honours :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Don't mind if I do. :) Ping me if you see any other chat weirdness in the next few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown by the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag added by Adam (a Stack Overflow developer), this issue appears to have been solved. I'm just posting this answer so the question doesn't stay in the Unanswered list.

> We had some issues with chat following a SQL server upgrade, but I believe those have been resolved now.
>
> <sub>-- [Adam ♦](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9759/messages-not-posting-in-chat#comment27274_9759)</sub>